# How to use font awesome and resize the place holder name after responsive

Tags: html, css

I am using the font awesome but its not working for my paragraph . I saved font  file in font folder. and how to resize  the place holder name after responsive

```
<html>
<title> Font Awesome</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">

</body>
</html>

//style.css

@font-face {
    font-family:"gotham-rounded-book";
    src:url('../fonts/gotham-rounded-book.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Comment: Ok, what's not working? As for resize of placeholder, what have you tried?

Comment: i am not tried  because i dont have any idea about place holder size

Answer (score 0):

```
Regarding Paragraph:- First check the path for font assets. And call that font-family in css for paragraph.

Placeholder text can be changed only using jQuery or Javascript

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  if($(window).width()<768){
    if(!$('input[type=text]').val()) { 
         $('input[type=text]').attr("placeholder", "Type your answer here");
      } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply pankaj .please check the code above i typed the same path but connected .Please assist me more